# jQuery is not loading in new window in Joomla

Tags: joomla-3.x, jquery

**jQuery is not loading in new window in Joomla**

I have a page `default.php` in component module.
`default.php` contains

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
```

And in `default.php` jQuery is successfully loaded and in console shows

```
jQuery().jquery;
"1.12.4"
```

---

In my  `default.php` file I have a link, when I click that link it open a new window.

```
window.open("?view=report&format=raw&uid=" + ibonum, 'myWin', 'toolbar=no, directories=no, location=no, status=no, menubar=no, resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes, width=960, height=741');
```

In that page I use the code to load jquery:

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
```

But here (new window) jQuery is not loaded. Console shows:

```
jQuery().jquery;
 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

And also here `$document->addScript` is also not working.

so my question is: **How I load jQuery in new window i Joomla?**

My joomla version is  `3.9.2`

Comment: Could you please also copy your jQuery script in your question, the script you want to run in the new window. Do you run that script in the original window, or that script should be running in the new window only?

Comment: In orginal window jquery is working, but in new window jquery not working. Since there is no scope for  jquery in new window I can't write any jquery code in new window.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected. As indicated by `format=raw` parameter in the URL, the page you are trying to open is a raw document and not a HTML document. Raw document only renders what's outputted by the component's view.

Comment: can I change to `format=html` , but gives `500 - Layout default not found.`

Comment: It means there's no `default.php` layout file for `report` view.

Comment: How can I make it working? any suggestions??

Comment: Sharky got the point since his answer is giving the light on the question. @DeepuSasidharan - You should just create default.php file in the report folder (and view) of whatever your component is and a layout of the page should be built up in that file. Please study Joomla and the documentation of Joomla at least a bit before you try to work with Joomla at all...